# Ant-Android Application - how can i include a non-android project?

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, continuous-integration, build-automation

I've some troubles with ant, `jenkins` and android. I've followed this [tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project)   and it worked fine! But now I've a little problem... my android-project needs to import another project, which isn't an android project and so, has no `Androidmanifest.xml`

when I try to write following line in console:

```
android update project -p othernonandroidproject
```

I'm getting the error: `othernonandroidproject` is not a valid project < AndroidManifest.xml not found>.

can someone help me? it's very important :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to make a jar of your third-party project and put it in the `lib` directory of your android project?

*Update:*

Your command example is wrong, you may mean

`android update project -p ./ -l relative_path/to_an/android_lib_project`

but then, it doesn't fit your need because you need to import a third-party/non-android-specific java support library.

To use that kind of support package in your ant build process, you just need to put the library jar to the lib directory and it will be automatically taken into account by the build process. From your comments, I deduce that the real question is: how to double manage a WIP third-party library for continuous integration of an android project? Right? Then you should update your question to reflect that. Do not forget that the quality of the answers will be directly correlated with the quality of the question (thus I admit the low quality of my answer).

Now, I have never used jenkins but my understanding is that it relys on ant for the build process ⇛ go for ant targets. If you apply CI to both your android package and your support package, you could make push/pull targets on your projects: an ant push target on your support package to deliver the latest successful build resulting jar of your support package and an ant -pre-compile pull target on your android project.

If you don't do CI on your support package, then just push a tagged version to the vcs of your android project or compile it on the fly as a -pre-compile target…

You could inject the bare .java files by using a -pre-compile ant target (copying the files) but I'm not sure that will be a good solution.

Comment: hey, thank you for your fast reply. i havent tried it yet, because some other people are still developing in this common-project. it's just a project, which stores all of common classes needed by android-client and server.

Comment: If the third party project contains any android-related commons definitions you should make an android lib-project (android create lib-project + android update project_that_depends_on_the_lib_project) else just package that project and use it by pushing the jar to lib…

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. This common-package is currently under development, so it's no choice for me, to create a jar of it every time something changes :( - is there another solution?

Comment: You could add a custom target in your ant build.xml file to build the dependency and inject the resulting jar for you in the local lib dir. You'll have to chain the build process as <target name="-pre-compile" depends="your_third_build_target"/>

Comment: okay, i could try this ;), but i think it don't solve my other problem: we're using ant just for jenkins build automation, for ourself, we're simply debugging via eclipse and without ant. So I have to get this running in eclipse, too... :( And well, i could make a jar and import this, but I find it very complicated...

Comment: ant is used without any problems within eclipse. I know nothing about jenkins but at some point, for CI purposes, you'll just have to build and you'll have to use ant for this… + I don't use eclipse: just GNU/Emacs, the command-line and ant…

Comment: can i just "add" the new generated library to the specified android folder, everytime there is an update in this common-project? maybe i can configure jenkins in this way, that jenkins automatically rebuild the jar and replace the lib in the client-application. what do you think of this option? :) thanks for all of your ideas!